# Syntax Error in config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I'm creating an admin page for an app that sends questions to MP's.

Upon running my rails server, I am getting the error:

> syntax error, unexpected tString, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   get '', to: 'dashboard #index' as '/admin'.

This is my code in routes.rb where I'm getting the error:

```
root to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
namespace :admin do
  get '', to: 'dashboard #index', as '/admin'
  resources :questions, :users
end
```

And this is my dashboard controller:

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController      
  before_filter :authorize

  def index
  end
end
```

I am trying to create a route so I have a url for my site like:
`http://example.com/admin`

Comment: Why the downvote? If something is wrong with my question do let me know. Some people are new to this.

Answer (score 3):

Missing colon after `as`, and a space as indicated by DickieBoy

```
get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/admin'
```

Comment: Apparently, admin/dashboard is not a supported controller name. Perhaps unrelated to my previous question, do you know why this might be? Error occurred both when I ran rake routes and rails server

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the ':' after 'as'.

```
get '', to: 'dashboard #index', as: '/admin'
```

Comment: Apparently, admin/dashboard is not a supported controller name. Perhaps unrelated to my previous question, do you know why this might be? Error occurred both when I ran rake routes and rails server